# What is the Difference between Dart console-full and console-simple application?

Tags: dart

While learning dart I came across to these type of console application, so I just want to know What is the Difference between Dart **console-full** and **console-simple** application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both templates generate a Dart project with some default files:

- `.dart_tool/package_config.json`
- `.gitignore`
- `.packages`
- `analysis_options.yaml`
- `CHANGELOG.md`
- `pubspec.lock`
- `pubspec.yaml`
- `README.md`

But does then also create Dart files which depends on the type of template:

**console-simple**

Creates a very basic Dart project with a single Dart file named `bin/<project_name>.dart` with the content:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  print('Hello world!');
}
```

**console-full**

Create a more complete Dart project where we split the code into `bin/`, `lib/`, and `test/`. The description in the auto-generated `README.md` file does explain the file structure:

> A sample command-line application with an entrypoint in `bin/`, library code
> in `lib/`, and example unit test in `test/`.

The project makes use of the `test` package for unit testing so the project will by default include this package in the `pubspec.yaml`.

Following Dart files is generated to make use of the three directories:

```
// bin/project_name.dart
import 'package:project_name/project_name.dart' as project_name;

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  print('Hello world: ${project_name.calculate()}!');
}
```

```
// lib/project_name.dart
int calculate() {
  return 6 * 7;
}
```

```
// test/project_name_test.dart
import 'package:project_name/project_name.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('calculate', () {
    expect(calculate(), 42);
  });
}
```